# Android Youtube Webview Full screen back press exit the app

Tags: android, webview

Youtube Full screen work fine but when i press back button then app automatically exit. I want that, when i will press the back button from full screen video mode then i want to go back my previous page. Here is my code:

```
package com.example.youtubewebview;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final WebView webView=findViewById(R.id.webView);
        final FrameLayout frameLayout=findViewById(R.id.myFrame);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        webView.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCCjv5s3o3IuKPH0KycfyWHg");

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onShowCustomView(View view, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback) {
                super.onShowCustomView(view,callback);
                webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                frameLayout.addView(view);

            }
            public void onHideCustomView () {
                super.onHideCustomView();
                webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override onbackpressed and handle it manually

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
// write your logic here to trigger backpressed menually if you want to enable for somecondition
    return;
}
```

and if you want to manage backpressed in web view you can create interface implementation and pass it to the webview to get backpressevent in your webview and by that you can manage things.

Refer this link for [webviewcallbacks](https://www.tanelikorri.com/tutorial/android/communication-between-application-and-webview/)